# How to show image after clicking the image in modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My HTML Code is like this :

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Launch demo modal</button>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">


            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

My Javascript Code is like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    htmlData = '';
    htmlData = 'Photos<a href="#" id="hotel_photo" data-hotel-code="nases">(Click to View)</a><br><br>';
    htmlData += '<div class="imageHotel"></div>';

    $('#myModal').find('.modal-body').html(htmlData);

    $(".imageHotel").hide();
    $(document).on("click", "#hotel_photo", function(event){
        $(".imageHotel").toggle();
        event.preventDefault();
        htmlData += '<div id="gallery_hotel">';

            htmlData = '<img id="largeImage" src="http://www.workshop.rs/demo/gallery-in-4-lines/images/image_01_large.jpg" />';

        htmlData += '</div>';


        htmlData += '<div id="thumbs_hotel">';

            htmlData += '<img src="http://www.workshop.rs/demo/gallery-in-4-lines/images/image_01_thumb.jpg" />';
            htmlData += '<img src="http://www.workshop.rs/demo/gallery-in-4-lines/images/image_02_thumb.jpg" />';
            htmlData += '<img src="http://www.workshop.rs/demo/gallery-in-4-lines/images/image_03_thumb.jpg" />';
            htmlData += '<img src="http://www.workshop.rs/demo/gallery-in-4-lines/images/image_04_thumb.jpg" />';
            htmlData += '<img src="http://www.workshop.rs/demo/gallery-in-4-lines/images/image_05_thumb.jpg" />';

        htmlData += '</div>';

        $('.imageHotel').html(htmlData);

    });


    $('#thumbs_hotel').delegate('img','click', function(){
                                               // alert('tes');
        $('#largeImage').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb','large'));

    });

</script>
```

Demo is like this : https://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/10td0yww/1/

When I click the image in the image list, the image has not changed. Though I already call id thumb hotel.

When I not using modal. It's working

When I using modal. It's not working

Any solution to solve my problem?

Thank you very much

Comment: I update my jsfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on correct path of using delegated-events approach for dynamically generated elements. However, You should bind the using [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

> As of jQuery 1.7, `.delegate()` has been superseded by the `.on()` method,

When binding event use `imageHotel` as parent static containeras you are replacing `thumbs_hotel` element completely.

```
$('.imageHotel').on('click', '#thumbs_hotel img', function() {
    $('#largeImage').prop('src', this.src.replace('thumb', 'large'));
});
```

[image: jsFiddle]

Comment: I need you help. look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37209847/how-to-send-parameter-json-array-when-modal-open

Answer (score 2):

Here is update to your fiddle

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/10td0yww/4/)

Make use of this

```
// bind the click event
        $('#thumbs_hotel').off().on('click', 'img', function () {
          console.log($(this).attr('src'));
          $('#largeImage').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb','large'));
        });
```

Put it inside the click event when the inserting the images on the pop by the **"Click to view"**

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
$('body').on('click', '#thumbs_hotel img', function () {
  $('#largeImage').attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('thumb', 'large'));
});
```

Below lists which version you should be using

> $(selector).live(events, data, handler); // **jQuery 1.3+**
>
> $(document).delegate(selector, events, data, handler); // **jQuery
>   1.4.3+**
>
> $(document).on(events, selector, data, handler); // **jQuery 1.7+**

Answer (score 1):

you should move your

```
$('#thumbs_hotel').delegate('img','click', function(){
    $('#largeImage').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb','large'));
});
```

inside the `$(document).on("click")` 
because the event is not binded in newly appended dom

[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/10td0yww/2/)